# Path Analysis with Interactions

Tags: interaction, meta-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, masem

I'm trying to simulate what is essentially a multiple linear regression for MASEM with some interaction terms. The idea is to have something like this:

[image: Path Model]

In this model, the S variables are all likely correlated and I'm assuming that the mod variable is not correlated with the S variables, but I have included it's covariance in the model just in case there is some relation. However, I specifically want to test if the mod variable has interactions with the S -> DV regression paths. I've drawn one singular line for simplicity, but "Mod" should regress on each S -> DV path here. All of these variables should be numeric values. Also, the S variables are all positively associated with DV, but Mod is negatively associated with DV. However, I'm not sure yet if I can directly test this for my model, so for now I simply included it as a another regression path in the path analysis. Also, while the S variables are related, I explicitly label them as manifest because I want to directly test the interactions for each variable rather than a single latent variable path.

I've tried simulating this model by using this data:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(lavaan)
library(tidyverse)
library(semPlot)

#### Sim Data ####
set.seed(123)
DV <- rnorm(n=1000)
S1 <- DV *.40 + rnorm(n=1000)
S2 <- DV *.40 + rnorm(n=1000)
S3 <- DV *.40 + rnorm(n=1000)
S4 <- DV *.40 + rnorm(n=1000)
MD <- DV * -.40 + rnorm(n=1000)
df <- data.frame(S1,S2,S3,S4,MD,DV) %>% 
  as_tibble()
df
```

Then I fit the model in `lavaan`:

```
#### Model Preds ####
model <- "
DV ~ a*S1 + b*S2 + c*S3 + d*S4 + e*MD 
INT1 := a*e 
INT2 := b*e 
INT3 := c*e 
INT4 := d*e
"

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- sem(model,
           df)

#### Plot Model ####
semPaths(fit,
         whatLabels = "std",
         style = "lisrel",
         curve = 2,
         residScale = 10,
         edge.label.cex = .8)
```

But the path model doesn't look correct...it shows covariances with all of the predictors but it doesn't appear to model the interactions in the plot from what I can see.

[image]

However, running `summary(fit, standardized = T)`, it appears to have at least some part showing the interactions I modeled at the end of the summary:

```
lavaan 0.6-12 ended normally after 1 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                         6

  Number of observations                          1000

Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                 0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv
  DV ~                                                         
    S1         (a)    0.223    0.022   10.129    0.000    0.223
    S2         (b)    0.191    0.023    8.341    0.000    0.191
    S3         (c)    0.218    0.022    9.747    0.000    0.218
    S4         (d)    0.217    0.022    9.789    0.000    0.217
    MD         (e)   -0.222    0.022   -9.951    0.000   -0.222
  Std.all
         
    0.251
    0.202
    0.234
    0.239
   -0.241

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv
   .DV                0.535    0.024   22.361    0.000    0.535
  Std.all
    0.545

Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv
    INT1             -0.050    0.006   -7.747    0.000   -0.050
    INT2             -0.043    0.006   -6.806    0.000   -0.043
    INT3             -0.048    0.007   -7.134    0.000   -0.048
    INT4             -0.048    0.007   -7.263    0.000   -0.048
  Std.all
   -0.061
   -0.049
   -0.056
   -0.057
```

Is this correctly modeled? Or am I doing something wrong here? And can I include these interactions without regressing the Mod variable on DV?

Comment: You have introduced a new tag masem, can you write a tag wiki?

Comment: Sure! Just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not simulating a moderated regression model. An interaction term is the product term of two variables. Also S1 to S5 are the predictors and not the outcome, in contrast to your specification in your simulation code. Assuming two predictors S1 and S2, one moderator M, example simulation code could look like this:

```
    set.seed(123)
    n <- 1000
    S1 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    S2 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    M  <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    DV <- 3 + 0.2*S1 + 0.3*S2 + 0.1*M + 0.1*S1*M - 0.1*S2*M + rnorm(n,0,0.5)
    
    df <- data.frame( S1, S2, M, DV )
```

Note that S1*M defines one of the interaction terms. To fit the model in lavaan use

```
    library( lavaan )
    m <- 'DV ~ S1 + S2 + M + S1:M + S2:M'
    fit <- sem(m, data = df)
    summary( fit )
```

The ":" asks lavaan to make the product terms internally.

Good luck
Stefan

Comment: Thanks. I ran this myself and figured out that the product terms are not plotted in the way I anticipated (they show up as S1: and S2:) which led to my confusion when I first used the `:` operator. Much appreciated Stefan.